# How to add 2 months in a date in PHP inside an HTML codes?

Tags: php, html, date

I'm new to PHP and I want to add 2 months to a specific date in an html code. How can I do it? Please guide me through,

Here's the code I use:

```
    private function inputExpiryDate() {
    $value = $this->expiryDate;
    $html = "";
    $html .= '<label for="expirydate">Expiry Date:</label>';
    $html .= '<input type="text" readonly name="expirydate" id="expirydate" value="'.$value.'">';
    $html .= '<input type="button" id="expirydatebutton" onclick="getExpiryDate()">' . PHP_EOL;
    return $html;
}
```

Question is how will I add this

```
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +2 month"); ??
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you add $value = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($value)) . " +1 month");  before $html="";?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to decompose the `$date` value to use it when doing relative date changes. This should just work as expected:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$date +1 month"));
```

Comment: Won't negative it, but your exemple does not work with d/m/Y

Answer (score 2):

After

```
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 month");
```

Add line

```
echo date("Y-m-d", $date);
```

As first sentence will return you Unix Timestamp so you again need to convert it to readable format

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add `date('Y-m-d)` like this `date('Y-m-d',strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 month"))`